# Symfony/ Api platorm/JWT get the current user after login

Tags: symfony, jwt, api-platform.com

Good morning to all
Please i need help. I am using  JWT Authentication and all works well.But my problem is to retreive the current user after the login. I saw in the documentation that i can create a controller to do so, but after doing that i get the error of id parameter not given.
Here is my controller related to the user entity

```
// api/src/Controller/GetMeAction.php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class GetMeAction
{
    /**
     * @param Security
     */
    private $_security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->_security = $security;
    }

    /**
     * @Route(
     *     name="get_me",
     *     path="get/me",
     *     methods={"GET"},
     *     defaults={
     *         "_api_resource_class"=User::class,
     *         "_api_item_operation_name"="get_me"
     *     }
     * )
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request): User
    {
        return $this->_security->getUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: change `_api_item_operation_name` for `_api_collection_operation_name`.

Comment: this resolve the problem . Thanks yivi

Comment: There are a few proposals on GitHub issue [Best Practice for adding a /me route](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/477) on how to do this without a controller since [using custom controllers is discouraged](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answer is right, but you forgot to Extend you controller from abstract one:

```php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class AdminController extends AbstractController
{
}
```

If you want to get User in the service, you can Inject Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface in your __construct()

and you can get user like:

```php
public function getUser(): ?User
{
    $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();

    if (!$token) {
        return null;
    }

    $user = $token->getUser();

    if (!$user instanceof User) {
        return null;
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im using symfony 5.3, i wanted to use the api platform normalization and the item operation "get" to keep all the custom config, security, services, ...
So I used the `forward()` method in a controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/user/me", name="get_me")
 */
public function getMe(): Response
{
    $router = $this->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->get('api_users_get_item');
    $defaults = $router->getDefaults();
    return $this->forward($router->getDefault('_controller'), array_merge($defaults, [ 'id' => $this->getUser()->getId()]));
}
```